# apache ant loadfile with new line in the results

Tags: ant

I am trying to use LoadFile from Apache Ant to read a file which will have only the date in it. I am using this date to generated target file with appended date.

```
`<loadfile property="DATE" srcFile="DATE.txt" />`
```

Source file: ABC.txt
Target file: ABC_`$`{DATE}.txt
File DATE.txt content is 10182017

But the target file is being created as 
ABC

_10182017.txt

Is there a way I can avoid the new/next line while reading the date from the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this problem with nested `filterchain` functions.

```
<loadfile property="DATE" srcfile="DATE.txt">
    <filterchain>
        <striplinebreaks />
    </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```

Check out https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html for more details.